# Regex to find all Strings enclosed between two Strings in Dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'd like to find all occurrences of strings in a long string which are placed between a set of two specific strings.

For eg.

```
String s = "abcdText('hello')abcd efghText('world')";
```

The regex pattern of strings would be `Text('` and next `'` and the results should be the List of strings enclosed between the pattern. Hence the expected output should be:

```
[hello, world]
```

After some searches, I found [this](https://regex101.com/r/VO3qkp/4). This explains my use case but it is in PHP and only meant to find digits.

Comment: You can try this RegEx : https://regex101.com/r/l4C4q3/1

Comment: i don't see `world` is enclosed with the text `efgh`. is it a typo?

Comment: As I understand, it is finding text between `('` and `')`. This may not help me my all usecases. I have a hard requirement of finding text between `Text('` and the next occurrence of `'`?

Comment: @Helio if you notice `world` is enclosed between `Text('` and next `'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
  String myString = "abcdText('hello')abcd efghText('world')";
  RegExp exp = RegExp(r"\('(.*?)'\)");
  List<String> _list =[];
  for (var m in exp.allMatches(myString)) {
    _list.add(m[1].toString());
   
  }
  
  print(_list);
```

[image]

EDIT

```
  String myString = "abcdText('hello')abcd efghText('world')";
  RegExp exp = RegExp(r"Text\('(.*?)'\)");
  List<String> _list =[];
  for (var m in exp.allMatches(myString)) {
    _list.add(m[1].toString());
   
  }
  
  print(_list);
```

Comment: As I understand, it is finding text between `('` and `')`. This may not help me my all usecases. Is it possible to find between `Text('` and the anext occurrence of `'`?

Comment: @VipiNNegi : check for edited answer.